# rightbarbutton disappear on tabbar n storyboard

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I'm using storyboard on xcode5.
and I want to display put right bar button on navigation within tabbar.

structure is tabbar controller -> navigation controller -> view controller

I tried following code on view controller.
But, Nothing is displayed.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
UIBarButtonItem *addButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"btn"
                                                              style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain
                                                              target:self
                                                              action:nil];
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = addButton;
}
```

Does someone know what's wrong?

[image]

Comment: what is your question tabbar or navigationbar

Comment: I'm using tabbar and navigationbar.

Comment: Check tintColor for bar button item

Comment: it was tintColor's problem.. I'm so stupid.. thank you so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your ViewDidLoad

```
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"More" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(toggleMenu:)];
```

or Storyboard

[image]

Comment: thank you for replying. I tried your reply. But, I couldn't... I added image on top.

Comment: check your image as invalid or image not available in your projects